# Primitive roots mod divisor of an integer

Tags: elementary-number-theory, primitive-roots

QN: Prove that if there exists a primitive root modulo n, then there exists a primitive root modulo every divisor of n.

If $a$ is a primitive root mod n, then $a^{x}\equiv 1$ mod n has least integer solution $x= ord_n(a)= \phi(n)$. If p is any prime divisor of n, then $a^{\phi(n)}\equiv a^{\phi(p)} \equiv 1$ mod p. From this how do I extend it to modulo a general divisor d of n?

$a^{\phi(d)} \equiv 1$ mod d seems to hold but how do I show $ord_d(a)= \phi(d)$?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you know modulo which numbers there is a primitive root ? Considering this criterion, the answer is no more difficult.

Comment: @Peter modulo primes? In that case there are $\phi(p-1)$ primitive roots. But considering a general divisor d, how do I show $\phi(d)$ is the least solution to $a^x \equiv 1  mod d$?

Comment: The numbers $n$ such there is a primitive root modulo $n$ are $1,2,4$ , the prime powers $p^k$ ( with prime $p$ and  $k\ge 1$ ) and twice those prime powers. Every divisor of such a number is of this kind.

Comment: If we do not use this criterion, I think, we cannot use the same base in general for the divisor. But what should help is $$d\mid n\implies \varphi(d)\mid \varphi(n)$$

Comment: @JCAA Thanks for giving me the heads up.  In an answer that I posted, I mis-interpreted the phrase "multiplicative group of integers mod $n$.  Since my answer was based on this misinterpretation, my answer was wrong.  Therefore, I have deleted my answer.